# Find VMID for running instance

Tags: garbage-collection, jstat, vmid

I have a webapp running on tomcat and I want to look at garbage collection during runtime using jstat.

I have the command:

```
jstat.exe -gc <vmid> 1000
```

How can I find what the `vmid` is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vmid` is essentially a PID of JVM process

You have multiple options to find PID of your JVM

- use generic OS tools such as `ps`
- use [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) tools from JDK
- use more elaborate version of [jps](https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools/blob/master/sjk-core/COMMANDS.md#jps-command) from [SJK](https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools) tools (i.e. it can display system properties of listed JVMs)